# Cannot scale frequency of a Core i7 2720QM

Tags: intel, cpu, frequency, scaling

I own a Dell Latitude E6520 with an Intel CPU (Core i7 2720QM). After installing cpufrequtils, I get the following message :

```
cpufrequtils 007: cpufreq-info (C) Dominik Brodowski 2004-2009
Veuillez rapportez les erreurs et les bogues à cpufreq@vger.kernel.org, s'il vous plait.
analyse du CPU 0 :
  **pas de pilotes cpufreq reconnu pour ce CPU**
  maximum transition latency: 4294.55 ms.
```

In English : **no cpufreq pilot found for this CPU.**

Thus my CPU runs always at full speed (2,2 GHz) which consume the battery and shorten its life. I don't either know how to activate turbo mode.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried installing [Jupiter](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/jupiter)

This app clocks down your processors when on battery to their lowest setting and kicks them back up once A/C power is restored. I have used other linux power mgmt tools but haven’t had a great experience. I have a system76 Pangolin and it’s pretty power hungry, it’s pretty much a mobile desktop and during the Natty / Oneiric releases of Ubuntu I was lucky to get 40 minutes on the beast. But that was because everything was running full power, After installing Jupiter and making some additional changes I managed to turn 40 minutes into about 1 hour & 45 minutes.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Cpufrequtils was very neat - till now. I'll give a chance to Jupiter. Regards,

Comment: Updated link: https://launchpad.net/jupiter-project OR homepage: http://jupiter.sourceforge.net/ **But it appears to be defunct.**